# Converting coordinates using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert, geodjango

In QGIS do I have a EPSG:4326 shapefile that shows the coordinates "-7148300 -3688500" and I need them in the format -64º -31º for further processing in a geodjango app.

However using ogrinfo I get this information from the shapefile:

> ```
> Feature Count: 22
> Extent: (-64.279736, -31.509785) - (-64.092643, -31.332019)
> Layer SRS WKT:
> GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
>     DATUM["WGS_1984",
>         SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
>     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
>     UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
> id: Integer (10.0)
> ```

How can I convert the values?

I found useful both solutions:

1. Getting the coordinates of a given feature id, within Geodjango shell, so I have a reference and work from there using a custom conversion function.
2. Know the mathematical equivalence between the two pairs of coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach: The Geodjango snippet :)

```py
>>> from django.contrib.gis.gdal import SpatialReference, CoordTransform
>>> ct = CoordTransform(SpatialReference(3857), SpatialReference(4326))
>>> pbt = fromstr('POINT(-7146947 -3694804)', srid=3857)
>>> pbt.transform(ct)
>>> print 'x: %s; y: %s; srid: %s' % (pbt.x, pbt.y, pbt.srid)
x: -64.2021172489; y: -31.4766257292; srid: 4326
```

Answer (score 4):

Your QGIS **project** CRS is set to Google Mercator, which is needed if you want Google or Openstreetmap background by using Openlayers plugin.

The **layer** CRS can (and should be) different from that, in your case WGS 84 in degrees.

If you want the coordinate display in degrees, but have a Google/OSM background: make a screen copy by `File -> Save Picture as`, add that picture to the canvas, delete the openlayers layer, Rightclick on the shapefile layer `-> Set Layer CRS for project`

The picture may look distorted the more away you are from the aequator, but thats what lat/lon coordinates are.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the PROJ.4 command line tool [cs2cs](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/man_cs2cs). This is certainly not the Geodjango shell solution that you would prefer, but may be best suited for what you are after. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is the updated solution I have found so far:

**First populating the PostGIS database**

```py
import os
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from models import UJ

mj = '/home/martin/data_dir/mapa/tramos.shp'
# Auto-generated `LayerMapping` dictionary for uj model
uj_mapping = {
    'id' : 'id',
    'geom' : 'MULTILINESTRING',
}

def run(verbose=True):
    lm = LayerMapping(UJ, mj, uj_mapping,
                      transform=False, encoding='utf-8')

    lm.save(strict=True, verbose=verbose)
```

**Then Using cs2cs** from the comment of @isolier I get the converted coordinates:

```
cs2cs +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +units=m +k=1.0 +nadgrids=@null +no_defs Then I enter "-7148300 -3688500 " without quotes and get: 64d12'51.377"W 31d25'41.939"S 0.000
```

**Then Using PostGIS**

```py
from mapa.models import UJ
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
pbt = fromstr('POINT(-64.202117 -31.476626)', srid=4326)
qs = UJ.objects.filter(geom__distance_lte = (pbt, D(km=3)))
len(qs)
for uj in qs.distance(pbt): print(uj.id, uj.distance)
```

I still look for a way to automate this, but I'm closer.